# Qt Qtermwidget wait for command

Tags: c++, qt, terminal

I hope this question makes sense, I am using [QTermWidget](https://github.com/zester/Quantum) to create an instance of QTermWidget in Qt Creator 2.4.1, as shown [here](https://github.com/zester/Quantum/tree/master/QTerminal). I am able to run it and send commands to the embedded terminal with no problems, however, I would like to be able to send a command to the terminal, wait for the terminal to finish, and then send the other command, like this:

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDir>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    ui->tabWidget->setUsesScrollButtons(true);

    QIcon::setThemeName("oxygen");
    this->setWindowIcon(QIcon::fromTheme("utilities-terminal"));

    console = new QTermWidget();

    QFont font = QApplication::font();
    font.setFamily("Monospace");
    font.setPointSize(12);

    console->setTerminalFont(font);
    console->setScrollBarPosition(QTermWidget::ScrollBarRight);
    console->setColorScheme("WhiteOnBlack");

    ui->tabWidget->insertTab(ui->tabWidget->currentIndex(), console,
                             QString(QDir::currentPath()));

    QString Home = "ls";
    QString enter = "\r";
    console->sendText(Home);
    // I would like the terminal to finish the previous command,
    // before sending the next one, right now it just proceeds to
    // the next line of code before it finishes.
    console->sendText(enter);

    console->sendText(QString cd);
    console->sendText(enter);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{   
delete ui;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Qt 2.4.1 ? Are you sure you are talking about right version or software?

Comment: I meant Qt Creator 2.4.1.

Comment: Well, Qt Creator version should be totally irrelevant, it's just an IDE (a glorified code editor). You are asking about how to do things in your own app, not about how to use the IDE, ate you not?

Comment: 2.4 is quite old btw, you might find it worth your while to update Qt Creator to latest version. It has some nice refactoring helpers, for example.

Comment: One more comment (no time to write proper answer), doing time consuming stuff like that in constructor is generally not good. Constructor should do just straightforward initialization/setup without delays. More complex things like user interaction are better to do separately.

Comment: @hyde Thank you for your comments. I will update Qt Creator. Also, the code I provided is a very simplified version of what I am working with, just to illustrate my question. A potential solution I found was to send the commands separated by `;`but I am not sure this is the best approach.